# react native import as is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

can the component be renamed with an alias?

some why its undefined and cannot be used.

when i use original name then everything is fine

*view/ClientPricelist.js* file

```
    export default function ClientPricelist({navigation, route, order_product, product_select}) { return null; }
```

*controller/ClientPricelist.js*

```
import {ClientPricelist as ClientPricelistView} from '../view/ClientPricelist';

export default function Index(){

    console.log(<ClientPricelistView/>);//in console its <UNDEFINED/>
    return <ClientPricelistView/>;//throws error its not named component
}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": 
   "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
   "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.2.4",
   "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
   "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
   "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
   "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
   "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
   "@shopify/flash-list": "1.4.3",
   "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
   "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
   "eas-cli": "^3.13.0",
   "expo": "^49.0.0",
   "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
   "expo-checkbox": "~2.4.0",
   "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
   "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
   "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
   "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
   "phpass": "^0.1.1",
   "project-can-json": "^1.0.1",
   "project-react-mvc": "^1.1.6",
   "project-rest-client": "^1.1.0-beta",
   "react": "18.2.0",
   "react-native": "0.72.6",
   "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.9.0",
   "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
   "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
   "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
   "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1"
"devDependencies": 
   "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
```

Comment: why your `ClientPricelist` return null ?

Comment: use `import default` instead destructuring

Comment: @DinhNguyen because it is a default export

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`default` exports could not de-structured, use `import default`

```
import default as ClientPricelistView from '../view/ClientPricelist';

export default function Index(){

    console.log(<ClientPricelistView/>);
    return <ClientPricelistView/>; component
}
```